# Missing Badges under iOS7

Tags: ios7, badge, uitabcontroller

I have custom tab controller graphics that did display badges on them.  Under iOS7, they no longer display.  Are badges handled differently under iOS7?

```
// loading the custom icons for first tab
UITabBarItem *tabicon1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NewItemsSelected.png"] tag:0];
[tabicon1 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NewItemsSelected.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NewItemsUnselected.png"]];
UIViewController *first = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
[first setTabBarItem:tabicon1];

// testing for waiting items
int items_waiting = [self itemsWaitingCheck:0:1];
if (items_waiting > 0)
{
    // displaying items waiting for the first tab
    tabicon1.badgeValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", items_waiting];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer discovered.  Apple changed the height of the tab controller bar, which shifted the badge display lower out of view, hidden behind my deliberately oversized graphics.  Now I will have to redesign my tab graphics, unless someone knows how to change the badge display position?